# How do I extract a news article using Jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to extract a news post from [link](http://www.hindustantimes.com/india/pathankot-attack-from-bsf-to-air-force-many-officers-set-to-face-action/story-jYb7gGEiScnWPBADVHH1CJ.html), what I have tried is to select it by class name using this code

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(newsLink).get();
Elements element = document.getElementsByClass("sty_txt");
story = element.text();
```

The problem is that the website has an inner div tag within `.sty_txt` for sharing options. When I populate the result of the above code in my app the paragraph begins with share (3 times).

Now how do I remove this share options and other clutters only to display the article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove some children from `.sty_txt` element:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(newsLink).get();
Element element = document.getElementsByClass("sty_txt").first();
Elements children = element.children();
for (Element child : children) {
    Elements subChildren = child.children();
    if(child.hasClass("share-icons-box") || child.hasClass("story_tag_smo") ||
        (subChildren.size() > 0 && subChildren.first().hasClass("st_readmore_sp"))){
        child.remove();
    }
}
String story = element.text();
System.out.println("Story: " + story);
```

This code will remove share buttons, tags and read more links.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use a CSS selector only:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(newsLink).get();
story = doc.select("div.sty_txt p:not(:has(span.st_readmore_sp))").text();
```